# Preventing a method from being overridden in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sealed

How do I prevent a method from being overridden in a derived class?

In Java I could do this by using the `final` modifier on the method I wish to prevent from being overridden.

How do I achieve the same in C#?
I am aware of using `sealed` but apparently I can use it only with the `override` keyword?

```
class A
{
    public void methodA()
    {
        // Code.
    }

    public virtual void methodB()
    {
        // Code.
    }
}

class B : A
{
    sealed override public void methodB()
    {
        // Code.
    } 
}
```

So in the above example I can prevent the `methodB()` from being overridden by any classes deriving from class `B`, but how do I prevent class `B` from overriding the `methodB()` in the first place?

Update: I missed the `virtual` keyword in the `methodB()` declaration on class A when i posted this question. Corrected it.

Comment: Is this a new feature in C# 4 to seal a method?

Comment: If you aren't overriding the method already then just don't decorate it with `virtual` then anything else that comes along will not be considered for method binding on your type.

Comment: I believe your methods in class A should be `virtual` if you're planning on overriding them.

Comment: @UweKeim - no, it has been around for awhile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @CAbbott - My mistake.. I updated the code to reflect the same.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045179/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. The `virtual` modifier specifies that a method can be overridden. Omitting it means that the method is 'final'.

Specifically, a method must be `virtual`, `abstract`, or `override` for it to be overridden.

Using the `new` keyword will allow the base class method to be hidden, but it will still not override it i.e. when you call `A.methodB()` you will get the base class version, but if you call `B.methodB()` you will get the new version.

Comment: It's frustrating in a language that allows so many things be explicitly spelled out, there isn't a keyword to explicitly say "this is not mean to ever be overrided", if only so you don't accidentally make it virtual later on without considering why it wasn't in the first place.

Comment: @Fund C#'s sister language (VB.NET) has `NotOverridable`, `NotInheritable`, `Overridable`, `MustOverride`, `MustInherit`.

Answer (score 33):

As you mentioned, you can prevent further overriding of MethodB in class B by using `sealed` **with** `override`

```
class B : A
{
    public sealed override void methodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class C cannot override this method now");
    }
}
```

Use of the `sealed` modifier **along with** `override` prevents a derived class from further overriding the method.

If you do not want `methodB` in class A to be overridden by any child classes, do not mark that method `virtual`. Simply remove it. virtual keyword enable the method to be overridden in child classes

```
public void methodA()
{       
}
```

Use `sealed` keyword on your classes to prevent further overriding of the class

Comment: Use of the sealed modifier prevents a class from deriving from `class A`. That's not what was asked for.

Comment: @KendallFrey : The question title made me think that it is about preventing further overriding. Thanks

Comment: @KendallFrey `sealed` can be applied to methods, provided that they are overrides as well. It prevents *further* overriding in derived classes (as Shyju points out.)

Answer (score 8):

In C#, a function not marked `virtual` (which also includes overrides of virtual functions) is effectively sealed and cannot be overridden.  So, your example code actually won't compile because the override keyword is not valid unless there is a method marked virtual with the same signature in a base class.

If A.methodB() were marked virtual, then you could override the method from A, but prevent it being further overridden in classes deriving more indirectly, using the `sealed` keyword exactly as you have shown.

One thing to keep in mind is that while method overriding can be prevented, method *hiding* cannot. Given your current definition of class A, the following definition of class B is legal and there's nothing you can do about it:

```
class B:A
 {
      public new void methodB()
            {
                    //code
            } 
  }
```

The `new` keyword basically "breaks" the inheritance/overriding hierarchy as it pertains to this one method; any reference to a class B, treated as a class B (or any further derived type) will use the implementation from class B and ignore the one from class A unless B's implementation specifically calls back to it. However, if you were to treat an instance of class B as a class A (by casting it or passing it as a parameter), then the "new" implementation is ignored.

This differs from overriding, where a class B that is being treated as a class A and truly overrides a virtual methodB would still use class B's override of the method. Also understand that method hiding is inferred (though you will get a compiler warning); if you declare a method with the same signature in a derived class and do not specify either new or override, the base class method will be hidden.

Comment: Great info on the `new` modifier. Didn't even know about that.

Answer (score 1):

In a base class, the sealed keyword is only used to prevent a class from being derived, but in inherited classes it can be used to prevent another inherited class from overriding the method.

To prevent a base class method from being overridden, just do not specify it as virtual.  In the example you provided, class B could not override `methodB` because `methodB` was not marked as virtual on the original class.

this will compile:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void methodA()
    {
        //code
    }
    public virtual void methodB()
    {
        //code
    }
}
class B:A
{
    public override void methodB()
    {
        //code
    } 
}
```

this will not:

```
class A
{
    public void methodA()
    {
        //code
    }
    public void methodB()
    {
        //code
    }
}
class B:A
{
    public override void methodB()
    {
        //code
    } 
}
```

EDITTED: clarified and corrected my original statement about the sealed keyword

Comment: `sealed` can indeed be used on individual methods, it's just that `sealed` cannot be used at the highest-level implementation of the method; it must be used on a method that is an override of a base implementation, basically negating the "virtual" keyword from higher inheritance levels when deriving further. So, you're wrong that it can't be used but it doesn't solve his problem anyway

Comment: @KeithS thanks for that.  I never saw it used to seal and overridden method before, but thanks for teaching me something new.  I have editted my answer appropriately